# Is memory management a concern with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory-management, webforms

Hai guys,

I want to know,is memory management a concern with asp.net mvc..

- comparision of memeory management in
  both asp.net mvc and web forms by experts

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is built on top of WebForms so they share lots of similarities as far as memory management is concerned (provided you use the default webforms view engine).

Comment: Is it really? I though they were both built on top of ASP.NET, but otherwise independant.

Comment: @Vilx: You're correct. WebForms and MVC are built on top of ASP.NET. MVC just happens to take advantage of WebForms as a view engine. You can swap it out for whatever you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no difference in worrying about memory in ASP.NET MVC and webforms. You have to do it in both cases. :)

To elaborate, they both are built on top of the same ASP.NET infrastructure, which is built on top of the .NET runtime. Thus, they use the same memory management as any other .NET application, web or otherwise.

The overhead of the frameworks themselves is negligible, the real memory usage will come from the objects **YOU** load in your application. If you get a lot of users (from comments - 200 to 500 per minute), you will need to think about scaling out horizontally. That is, having multiple web and DB servers (also known as a "cluster"). This requires a bit of thought from the very beginning of the development, but is not very difficult to do. There should be other resources on this subject which is outside of the scope of this question.